# NoMethodError in Spree::

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass


  <% @taxonomies.each do |taxonomy| %>
    <% cache [I18n.locale, taxonomy, max_level, @taxon] do %>
      <% if taxonomy.root.children.any? %>
```

Hello, please i'm trying to show the taxonomies to every page.
So i added this iteration to the header!

and tried to request with every page with application_cotroller decorator!

with:

```
module Spree
    module ApplicationControllerDecorator
      def some_action
        @taxonomies = Tataxonomy.all
        
      end
    end
end
```

but, still confusing on how to solve this!

Answer (score 0):

Use a debugger (or byebug) to show what `@taxonomies` returns.

I believe the name of the taxonomy model might be misspelled here in the method.

Should be like this:

```
@taxonomies = Taxonomy.all
```

and not like this:

```
@taxonomies = Tataxonomy.all
```

Comment: thank you for the help, but this is just a misspell!

Comment: what @taxonomies returns?

Comment: the same issue!

Comment: did you put a debugger or byebug before right after setting `@taxonomies` in the method?
if yes, does it return an error? If not, please put and post what the @taxonomies variable returns.